# disable async new buffer question

Tags: buffers, async

When I give a new async command with an interactively called async-shell-command, it gives a message "A command is running in the default buffer.  Use a new buffer? (y or n)". I think this behaviour is unnecessary, every time I'm giving a new command, I'll press y. Can I disable this behavior in some way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may be interested in creating a new/modified function of `shell-command` that does not seek confirmation.  You may also be interested in customizing the variable `async-shell-command-buffer`.  For a listing of the options, type `M-x describe-variable` or `C-h v`.

To see how this variable works within the function `shell-command`, type `M-x find-function RET shell-command RET`.

How did I find this out?  I typed `M-x find-function RET async-shell-command-buffer RET` and I did a word search in that library for "a command is running".  There are other methods to find this stuff out, like reading the manual that probably discusses the above-variable ... however, I usually just examine the code to figure stuff out.

Comment: I didn't know about find-function! answers like yours really help me do my research before coming here, so thank you for that.

Comment: I had this issue, too, and customizing `async-shell-command-buffer` did exactly what I needed. Thanks.

Comment: You may want to mention that this user option is documented under [`(emacs) Single Shell`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Single-Shell.html).

Comment: Thans for adding the How bit.  I suppose you did `M-x find-function RET shell-command RET` rather than `async-shell-command-buffer`.